# My PC Restarted for the reason i dont know

Tags: windows, virus, anti-virus

Hello I am using Windows 10 and i downloaded a file after opening it the sound glitched and my pc restarted and my pc logged out from my all accounts. Is this can be a virus my antivirus detected nothing and said the file was safe

Comment: hows about to verify the reason for the Reboot? Is minidump enabled and bluescreenviewer been used?

Comment: Check the event log to find out what the BSoD code is and research that in order to find out what the reason for the reboot was.

Comment: Another place to look for information is Reliability History (Control Panel, Security and Maintenance).